# GeoLocation When Browser is Inactive

Tags: javascript

I need to capture the user current location every 2 minutes so i have a setinterval event which is fired. In that event i capturing the user location.This works fine if my browser tab is active. But when i change the tab/browser minimised the event is not fired.
I have this following code which is fired

```
setInterval(() => this.GetUserLocation(), 120000);

  GetUserLocation() {
        console.log('Event Fired');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
             console.log(position);
        });
  }
```

I can see the first console statement is fired but not console in getCurrentPosition event.
How can i get user location when the application browser tab is not active?

Comment: You might achieve this by setting up a service worker. But browser support is not great.

Comment: @AndreasFurster Any documentation you can suggest to try with service worker?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745) is the documentation on the ServiceWorker possibilities with background Geolocation. Sadly there has been no progress on this essential functionality in over 2 years :-( IMHO W3C have a lot to answer for.

Please see my [Brotkrumen](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/travelmanager.html) Web App for a POC example. There is a readme file.

Again, IMO you should be using watchPosition but you can currently use Firefox to keep receiving location updates in the background.